# Finding invert pair of a cell pair in excel

Tags: excel, row, directed-graph, vba

I have a table that is an image of directed graph.

```
 John, Peter
 John, Dan
 Peter, John
 Dan, John
```

How to arrange rows in a such way that pairs would appear next to each other.
The result should look like:

```
 John, Peter
 Peter, John
 (this gap is for the sake of clarity)
 Dan, John
 John, Dan
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this in three parts:

**PART#1:**

Insert the following UDF in a standard module:

```
Public Function ReOrder(sIn As String) As String
    s = Replace(sIn, " ", "")
    ary = Split(s, ",")
    If ary(0) < ary(1) Then
        ReOrder = ary(0) & "," & ary(1)
    Else
        ReOrder = ary(1) & "," & ary(0)
    End If
End Function
```

**PART#2:**

Assuming you data is in column **A**, in B1 enter:

=ReOrder(A1)   and copy down

**PART#3:**

Sort cols **A** & **B** by **B**